# When publishing from visual studio 2019 to 1&1 FTP, updates to controllers/views are not showing but are working locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, hosting, publishing

I have created an MVC project in .NET core that seems to work fine when it is run locally, I have created a FTP publish profile in visual studio that appears to work and most of the pages appear on the website, but any changes i make to the views (such as adding a new link) do not seem to appear.
In one case, the admin page does not seem to publish at all.
This is also the case when making changes to any controllers (such as removing the Authorize tag).

I have the files set to "Copy Always" in the "Copy to output Directory" setting, I have also tried to strip the pages down to their bare bones just in case it was a code issue. But I cant think of much else that would cause this problem.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you resolved this? i am also facing this issue